# how i can cancel DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT from running

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

well for me I'm using this method to connect with internet service , the main problem is when i go to another storyboard , the method dispatch_get_global_queue won't stop , how i can stop it when i go to another storyboard

```
         let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            link = "http://nepraswebsite.com/new_lille/mobile_api/Products_list/index/BestView/1"

            if let url = NSURL(string: "http://nepraswebsite.com/new_lille/mobile_api/Products_list/index/BestView/1") {
                if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
                    SearchResult = JSON(data: data)
                }
            }
            self.didFinishLoadingSearch = true

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            HUD.show(.Progress)
        }
```

Comment: dispatch_async blocks are not cancellable.  You can look at NSOperations

Comment: found this for OBJ-C 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612503/ios-stop-global-queue-from-running ?

Comment: Yes, you can set a flag and check it in your code, but in this case the majority of the work is being performed by `contentsOfURL` and you can't change that code.  You can set a boolean in `viewWillDisappear` and check it in your closure if you want but it won't actually cancel the network operation

Comment: well i found  NSOperationQueue more easy , but how i can cancel it for NSOperationQueue ?

Comment: You still won't be able to cancel the `contentsOfURL`, but you can use an NSOperation to wrap the code you have and then check the `cancelled` property; this is effectively the same as setting your own boolean.  What is your real concern though?  Typically you just let the network operation complete and if the VC is no longer on screen it doesn't matter

Comment: NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://nepraswebsite.com/new_lille/mobile_api/Products_list/index/BestView/1") {
                if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
                    SearchResult = JSON(data: data)
                }
            }
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                    print("FINISHED")
                })
            })

Comment: i did that , if i go to another screen , it will stop alone !?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106820/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ahmed-safadi).